# swapping lines in a file in C

Tags: c, file, swap

hi i have encountered a problem while trying to implement bubble sort in my work on a file with many records in C.

I have to ONLY modify my file and not use any temp files doing this. whenever i try to swap two lines in my file i manage to write the second line instead of the first one successfully, but when i try to write the first line instead of the second one it seems to override lines after the second one. i know that it is because the length of the lines are not identical, but is there a way maybe by padding the lines with empty chars or something to do this with success?

here is the code: (can't seem to upload the variable declaration for some reason...)
the relevant part is in the if condition

```
for(j=0; j<linesNum-1; j++)
{
    for(k=0; k<linesNum-j-1; k++)
    {
        getline(&line1, &len, fp);
        pos = ftell(fp);
        getline(&line2, &len, fp);

        int i;
        char *tmp1 = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(line1));
        char *tmp2 = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(line2));
        strcpy(tmp1, line1);
        strcpy(tmp2, line2);

        token1 = strtok(tmp1, del);
        for(i=0; i<field; i++)
        {
            token1 = strtok(NULL, del);
        }
        token2 = strtok(tmp2, del);
        for(i=0; i<field; i++)
        {
            token2 = strtok(NULL, del);
        }

        if(strcmp(token1, token2) > 0)
        {
            fseek(fp, -(strlen(line1)+strlen(line2)), SEEK_CUR);
            fputs(line2, fp);
            //fsetpos(fp, &pos);
            fputs(line1, fp);

        }
        fsetpos(fp, &pos);
        free(tmp1);
        free(tmp2);
    }
}
```

}

from this file:

```
GNY1MJS2X,Mulan,Tony Bancroft,88,Harvey Fierstein,USA,7.5,Adventure
A1F9ENILS,Tropic Thunder,Ben Stiller,121,Steve Coogan,USA,7,Action
3YRMEJM1Y,The Departed,Martin Scorsese,151,Matt Damon,USA,8.5,Crime
NQMNMMOMR,The Girl with the Dragon Tattoo,David Fincher,158,Goran Visnjic,USA,7.8,Crime
FT2ULUNQ5,Die Hard with a Vengeance,John McTiernan,128,Aldis Hodge,USA,7.6,Action
```

I seem to get this:

```
A1F9ENILS,Tropic Thunder,Ben Stiller,121,Steve Coogan,USA,7,Action

GNY1MJS2X,Mulan,Tony Bancroft,88,Harvey Fierstein,USA,7.5,Adventure
YRMEJM1Y,The Departed,Martin Scorsese,151,Matt Damon,USA,8.5,Crime
NQMNMMOMR,The Girl with the Dragon Tattoo,David Fincher,158,Goran Visnjic,USA,7.8,Crime
FT2ULUNQ5,Die Hard with a Vengeance,John McTiernan,128,Aldis Hodge,USA,7.6,Action
```

which has an empty line between the first and the second line... and it also ruin the next lines.

Also, I sorted by one field delimited by comma, say the first field which is the movie ID.

*sorry for the messy way to write the files*

Comment: Where is the code you've got so far? We can't see what the problem is unless you include a [mcve]

Comment: Please show your code, a sample of the output and what you expect the output to be.

Comment: You never mentioned the word "adjacent" in your description of the two lines you're swapping. Any data *between* the lines will require re-positioning if the lines are different lengths. If the lines are the same lengths, OR they are adjacent to one another, it becomes a trivial case. Anyway, can't help you without your code to identify where you things went south, so best of luck.

Comment: Please show what you are getting

Comment: i added the code and yes i meant two adjacent rows every time. what do you mean by a trivial case?

Comment: Please post the **entire** source file as per [mcve]. See [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: There is NO need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [**Do I cast the result of malloc?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714) for thorough explanation. `char *tmp1 = malloc (sizeof *tmp1 * strlen(line1));` is fine. You may want to read `man 3 fputs` to find out where the additional `'\n'` is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are seeing corrupted output is that you are setting the position back to where line1 ended, even if the lines are swapped. This is a problem if line1 and line2 differ in length.

To minimize refactoring, you can seek backward the length of line1 on a swap and the length of line2 if you are not swapping.

Here is the update to your `if` statement, with `len1` and `len2` being the lengths of line1 and line2 respectively.

```
if(strcmp(token1, token2) > 0)
{        
    fseek(fp, -(len1 + len2), SEEK_CUR);
    fputs(line2, fp);
    fputs(line1, fp);
    fseek(fp, -len1, SEEK_CUR);
}
else
{
    fseek(fp, -len2, SEEK_CUR);
}
```

I also think you need to `rewind` in your outer loop if you want to go back through the file.

Answer (score 0):

First, consider your algorithm.

You're always comparing line *N* with line *N-1*.  After reading line 1, you always compare the current line (starting with line 2) to the previous one.  Keep track of the offset of line *N-1* in the file, because when you swap, you'll write line *N* to the *N-1* position.  You don't need to keep track of the *current* position, because after you seek and write the lines in swapped order, you'll be at the start of the next line.

So, you're  algorithm becomes something like:

```
do 
    pos = 0
    read prev
    while read curr
        if curr < prev
            seek to pos
            write curr
            write prev
            copy prev to curr (for the next comparison)
            nswapped++
        pos = ftell
    rewind
until nswapped == 0
```

I didn't try to debug your program because whatever is wrong is partly a function of complexity you've introduced.  If you minimize the work you're doing, any errors will become more obvious.